# Grant Applescript via Emacs Lisp permission for UI scripting

Tags: org-babel

I have a simple applescript, embeded in emacs-lisp, which uses the current `org-mode` heading to create a calendar event in Apple Calender.

However... because scripting Calendar directly is painfully slow, I am using the CalendarLib library, which requires the user to grant the script permission to access to the Accessibility features of the mac.

When I run the script, I get this popup message:

[image]

So I click "OK" and I am taken to System Preferences, where I then add Emacs to the list of approved apps for Accessibility

[image]

However, the next time I run the script, I get the same popup message. So something is not right...

Here is the script:

```
(do-applescript "
use AppleScript version \"2.4\" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use script \"CalendarLib\" version \"1.1.3\" -- put this at the top of your     scripts
use scripting additions

set d1 to current date
set d2 to d1 + 1 * hours
set theStore to fetch store
set theCal to fetch calendar \"activities\" cal type cal cloud event store theStore -- change to suit
set theEvent to create event event store theStore destination calendar theCal event summary \"A test event\" starting date d1 ending date d2 event location \"Around here\" event description \"some notes\" without runs all day store event event theEvent event store theStore with future events
return event identifier for event theEvent
")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The question is not clear. What does *"this does not seem to work"* mean? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Maybe `do-applescript` creates a process to execute AppleScript, and you're supposed to give necessary permissions to that process instead. I'll close the question for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with Mojave's new security measures. Updating to latest Emacs fixed the problem.